# Multiplication Table using neste for loops

Tags: for-loop, nested-loops, multiplication

I am trying to produce a square-formatted multiplication table with the output at the end using code below:

```
def multiplicationTable(maxValue):
    for i in range(1, maxvalue):
        for j in range(1, maxvalue):
            print(("{:6d}".format(i * j,)), end='')
    print()
print(multiplicationTable(1)
print(multiplicationTable(5))
print(multiplicationTable(10))
```

1

1 2 3 4 5

2 4 6 8 10

3 6 9 12 15

4 8 12 16 20

5 10 15 20 25

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30

4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40

5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60

7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

I get an error:

File "", line 7
print(multiplicationTable(5))
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

1. `print(multiplicationTable(1)` is missing a closing `)`.
2. You are using `maxValue` (with capital `V`) in your function definition while using `maxvalue` (with small `v`) in the function body.

Here is the new version:

```
def multiplicationTable(maxvalue): # maxvalue, not maxValue
    for i in range(1, maxvalue+1):
        for j in range(1, maxvalue+1):
            print(("{:6d}".format(i * j,)), end='')
        print()

multiplicationTable(1)
multiplicationTable(5)
multiplicationTable(10)
```

**EDIT 1:** Changed `range(1, maxvalue)` to `range(1, maxvalue+1)`

**EDIT 2:** Changed `print(multiplicationTable(n))` to `multiplicationTable(n)`

Comment: So that solves it-thanks. I also fixed the size of the multiplication table by indenting the last print() function to the right a bit more (under the last for loop). I am only left with one issue which is that I always get a "None" printed at the end- any ideas on why?

Comment: The call `print(multiplicationTable(1))` is generating a `None` because `range(start, stop)` generates integers from `start` to `stop-1`. So, in your case `range(1, 1)` generates integers from `1` to `0`. Therefore, if you want integers from `start` to `stop` (included), you should write `range(start, stop+1)`.

Comment: If this solves your problem, consider making it the accepted answer.

Comment: I did- so the argument is changed to ```range(1, maxvalue+1)``` and there is still a None displayed  after each print statement.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, in the sense that there is no return statement in the code. In this case, it implicitly returns `None`. So, when you print the return value of `multiplicationTable(n)` (which is `None`), you get `None` printed. I will edited my post to fix this issue.